# Renaming a selected Serial Port from COMX to COMY using C#

Tags: c#, port, rename

I can currently read and write to my serial ports on the machine, but I wish to be able to change from, for example, COM3 to COM4 within my program. I can't find a way to do this online - I've seen you can potentially use Windows Developer Kit but unsure as to whether that can be used with C#? Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to this article and its references. [Change COM port via registry, command line or software?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2002890/9014308)

Comment: It seems there is no .net api, but you can of course use P/Invoke to use another API.

Comment: Are you trying to change the I/O address of the port or just select different port number?  The port number is a string and can be change simply by changing from "COM3" to "COM4".  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2