# GET FRIENDLY PORT NAME Programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port

Anyone here has an idea where I can get the ports name listed in my PC?

[image: List of ports provided by Device Manager]

By using this code:

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count - 1
    cmbPort.Properties.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i))
Next
```

I could get `COM26` and etc. if any, but that's not what I want. Instead of retrieving `COM26`, I want `USB-SERIAL CH340` or `USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM26)`. How could I do that?

Comment: Related question with answer using WMI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937585/how-to-open-a-serial-port-by-friendly-name

Comment: This one is probably more related: [How do I get the friendly name of a COM port in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304986/how-do-i-get-the-friendly-name-of-a-com-port-in-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this .

```
Public Shared Function ListFriendlyCOMPOrt() As List(Of String)

    Dim oList As New List(Of String)

    Try
        Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM26%'")
            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                oList.Add(CStr(queryObj("Caption")))
            Next
        End Using

        Return oList

    Catch err As ManagementException
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
    End Try

    Return oList

End Function
```

That should work..

Answer (score 13):

I got mixed results from other answers.
I've come up with this code working better for me.

Add Reference to System.Management in your application

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
{
    var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

    var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();
    foreach (var i in portList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use WMI...
Add Reference to System.Management in your application
then,

shown on StackOverflow: [Getting Serial Port Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information)

```
using System.Management;
using System.IO;

        string result = "";
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_SerialPort"))
        {
            string[] portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();
            var tList = (from n in portnames join p in ports on n equals p["DeviceID"].ToString() select n + " - " + p["Caption"]).ToList();

            foreach (string s in tList)
            {
                result = result + s;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the name of the serial port; it is COM26. The name listed in the device manager is probably the name of the device providing the emulation.

Why do you want that name? If you describe your problem more completely, figuring out the solution will be easier.