# friendly port name combobox c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have a question about friendly name, I read a lot (really a lot) about how to get the friendly name. I even used the WMICodeCreator I have a code to put. But actually, I don't understand how to add this to my combobox menu. Here is my code. Actually, this one is showing the available COM port on the computer, but I would like to show the friendlyname of this one to make my application easier to use. How can I do to display friendly name instead of "COMx"?
I'm using Windows Form application on C#.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myport = new SerialPort();
    }

    private void portbox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        portbox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            portbox.Items.Add(port);
        }
    }

    private void butvalidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = portbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        myport.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370859/get-friendly-port-name-programatically)

Comment: I aldready used all that pages, all the codes, tried to add a lot of lines, moving, changing all compacting all I could read and nothing do what I want it's full of error message. especially with the  `ManagementObjectSearcher`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it came up when I was searching for something related, so I will post the code that I use for this precise purpose.

I get the list of `portNames` from `SerialPort`, then match those to the list of friendly names retrieved from a WMI query, and put them into a Dictionary with the port Name as the key and the friendly name as the value. Then I use this Dictionary as the Binding Source for the ComboBox. There are other ways to do this, but I find this approach simple and clear.

This terminology is a bit confusing because the ComboBox has a `DisplayMember` that it will use to display text and a `ValueMember` that it will provide as the `SelectedValue`. The `DisplayMember` is the dictionary "Value" and the `ValueMember` is the dictionary "Key."

```cs
using System.Management;
private void getAvailablePorts()
{
    // Get friendly names to go along with the actual portNames
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_SERIALPORT"))
    {
        var portDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames().OrderByDescending(s => s.GetAlphaNumericOrderToken()).ToArray<object>();
        var portList = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();

        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {
            // WMI does not always find all com ports so provide a null alternative
            var portDesc = portList.Where(p => p["DeviceID"].ToString() == portName.ToString()).Select(q => q["Caption"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault() ?? portName.ToString();
            portDictionary.Add(portName.ToString(), portDesc);
        }
        portComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(portDictionary, null);
        portComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        portComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";

        // I set my comboBox Selected entry to be the one with a friendly name 
        // beginning with "Teensy" (of course yours will be different, 
        // or you can leave this out)
        portComboBox.SelectedIndex = portComboBox.FindString("Teensy");  // -1 if not found
        if (portComboBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            portComboBox.Selected = 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// Since the ComboBox text is now different from the value, 
// you have to specifically get the SelectedValue of the ComboBox 
// rather than just its text. 
var _port = new SerialPort(portComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
```